Login/Logout feature: When accessing the page via direct url, the react page is accessible even after logging out
I'm trying to implement the Login/Logout feature in a React app. For the login functionality, I'm using Google OAuth login. When I tried to access a page via a direct URL after logging out, say "http://localhost:5000/dashboard", instead of redirecting to the login page, the app is redirecting to the dashboard page.
I have also added console.log statements to see if the value is getting set properly for the "isAuthenticated" flag, and indeed, it is getting set properly. Thanks for any advice/suggestions/pointers.


//LoginForm.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [authenticated, setauthenticated] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem(localStorage.getItem("authenticated") || false)
  );

  function handleCallbackResponse(response) {
    console.log("localstorage: " + localStorage.getItem("authenticated"));
    console.log("Encoded JWT ID token:" + response.credential);
    var userObject = jwtDecode(response.credential);
    console.log(userObject);
    if (userObject && userObject["email_verified"]) {
      console.log("login form authenticated");
      setauthenticated(true);
      localStorage.setItem("authenticated", true);
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    /*global google */
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id:
        "some_client_id",
      callback: handleCallbackResponse,
    });

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("signInDiv"), {
      theme: "outline",
      size: "large",
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="signInDiv"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;





//Dashboard.jsx

import { useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { tokens } from "../../theme";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("authenticated"));
  return <p>Dashboard</p>;
};

export default Dashboard;





//PrivateRoute.jsx
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("authenticated");
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log("isAuthentciated:" + isAuthenticated);
  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <>{children}</>
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      replace={true}
      to="/login"
      state={{ from: `${location.pathname}${location.search}` }}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;





//App.js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Topbar from "./scenes/global/Topbar";
import Sidebar from "./scenes/global/Sidebar";
import Dashboard from "./scenes/dashboard";
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { ColorModeContext, useMode } from "./theme";
import LoginForm from "./scenes/global/LoginForm";
import PrivateRoute from "./scenes/global/PrivateRoute";

function App() {
  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();
  const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);
  const location = useLocation();

  // Function to check if the current location matches certain paths
  const shouldShowSidebar = () => {
    const { pathname } = location;
    return !["/login", "/signup"].includes(pathname);
  };

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">
          {shouldShowSidebar() && <Sidebar isSidebar={isSidebar} />}
          <main className="content">
            {shouldShowSidebar() && <Topbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar} />}
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/login" element={<LoginForm />} />

              <Route
                path="/dashboard"
                element={
                  <PrivateRoute>
                    <Dashboard />
                  </PrivateRoute>
                }
              />
            </Routes>
          </main>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;





//Topbar.jsx - Logout Button

import { Box, IconButton, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ColorModeContext, tokens } from "../../theme";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import LightModeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LightModeOutlined";
import DarkModeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DarkModeOutlined";
import NotificationsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NotificationsOutlined";
import SettingsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SettingsOutlined";
import PersonOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlined";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import * as React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Topbar = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const colorMode = useContext(ColorModeContext);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    localStorage.setItem("authenticated", false);
    navigate("/login");
  };

  const menuId = "primary-search-account-menu";
  const renderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      id={menuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      {/* <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem> */}
      <MenuItem onClick={handleLogout}>Log out</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" p={2}>
      {/* SEARCH BAR */}
      <Box
        display="flex"
        backgroundColor={colors.primary[400]}
        borderRadius="3px"
      >
        <InputBase sx={{ ml: 2, flex: 1 }} placeholder="Search" />
        <IconButton type="button" sx={{ p: 1 }}>
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>

      {/* ICONS */}
      <Box display="flex">
        <IconButton onClick={colorMode.toggleColorMode}>
          {theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? (
            <DarkModeOutlinedIcon />
          ) : (
            <LightModeOutlinedIcon />
          )}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <NotificationsOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <SettingsOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
          <PersonOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
      {renderMenu}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Topbar;



